# Is there any way to make hair particles follow the z axis?

Tags: particles, normals

I'm populating a hillside with grass and would like the grass to grow straight up from their origins and not along the hill's normals.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that perfectly vertical grow would seem "natural", but if you need that, you can set Z axis velocity, using advanced settings:

[image]

Otherwise, you could also use "particle edit" mode to "comb" your grass as you wish:

[image]

then you comb "hair"

[image]

to get this, for example:

[image]

If you manually edit particles, your particle system gets some what locked, after. You can always revert those edit, use the "free edit" button on the particle settings, then.

Finally, and otherwise, you could use "a curve guide": https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/force_fields/types/curve_guide.html

That needs another bezier object with force field "curve guide" set, and then activate a force field effect of the same type on your hair object. Like this:

[image]

Remember, you could also use more than one particle systems, so to get some variation, and each can be using different methods and settings...

Comment: Wow, three different methods and illustrated too. Thanks so much, m.ardito. That was very generous of you.

Comment: FYI, you can also add a bit of brownian effect to break the regularity (you can find it under the newtonian physics part).